# Proving a function space is not open

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Theorem.** Consider the metric space $R = \{g: [0,1]: \to \mathbb{R} : ||g||_{\infty} \text{ is finite}\}$. The distance between two functions in the space is given by the sup norm. Prove that the set of positive functions in this space is not open in $X$.

---

**My attempt at a proof.** Define the set $B = \{g \in  G: g(x) > 0 \text{ for $x \in [0,1]$}\}$. Consider its complement, 
$$
B^c = \{g \in R: g(x) \leq 0 \text{ for $x \in [0,1]$}\}.
$$
It suffices to show that $B^c$ is closed, as this would imply that $B$ is open. Let $g$ be a limit point of $B^c$.  (We will show $g \in B^c$, meaning $B^c$ is closed, and we're done.) Then any deleted neighborhood, $N'_{\epsilon} (g)$, of $g$ contains some point of $B^c$. That is, $N'_{\epsilon} (g) \cap B^c \neq \emptyset$. So there is some $h \in N'_{\epsilon} \cap B^c$ such that $h \in B^c$. Thus, $h(x) \leq 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Assume $g \not \in B^c$ for a contradiction. Then $g \in B$. So $g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. As $[0,1]$ is a closed, bounded interval, there exists a minimum, $\alpha$, and a minimum function value, $g(\alpha)$. Of course, $g(\alpha) > 0$ by construction. Call $\delta = g(\alpha)$. Then, consider the open ball 
$$
B_{\frac{\delta}{2}} (g) = \{h \in R: \rho_{\infty} (g,h) < \frac{\delta}{2}\}.
$$
But all functions, $h$, in this ball are greater than $0$. Therefore, it contains no elements of $B^c$, a contradiction to the fact that $g$ is a limit point. Thus, $g \in B^c$, and $B^c$ contains all of its limit points and is closed. Since $B^c$ is closed, $B$ is open.

---

Comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question asks you to show that $B$ is not open, right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: But you are proving $B$ is open...?

Comment: Oh, I proved the opposite. That... was not supposed to happen. I cannot spot a flaw in my proof, either.

Comment: Note that $B^c = \{ g : g(x) \le 0$ for **some** $x\in [0,1]\}$.

Comment: This is true. I will revise my attempt with this in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Assume $g \not \in B^c$ for a contradiction. Then $g \in B$. So $g(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. As $[0,1]$ is a closed, bounded interval, there exists a minimum, $\alpha$, and a minimum function value, $g(\alpha)$. Of course, $g(\alpha) > 0$ by construction.

The existence of such $\alpha$ is crucial in your argument. However, the function $g$ might not be continuous, so such a $\alpha$ might not exist. For example,

$$ g(x) = \begin{cases} x & x\in (0,1], \\ 1 & x=0.\end{cases}$$

is in $B$ but don't have a minimum. Indeed you can check that for this particular $g$, $N_\epsilon (g)$ is not contained in $B$ for all $\epsilon >0$. Thus $B$ is not open.

Your argument can be used to show that the set of positive **continuous** functions is open in the space of continuous function (with $\| \cdot\|_\infty$-norm).

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure I fully understand the argument: the argument is that if $B$ is open, then every function within it must have some open ball around it that is contained entirely in $B$. But we've been able to find some $g$ that is not in the interior of $B$, so $B$ cannot be open. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @AdamtheNumberTheorist